# Magento 2.3.0 — Shipping Method Fetching

Tags: shipping-methods, magento2.3.0

Does anyone knows or has an answer(explanation) to the following questions:

- How does **`Magento 2.3.0`** **`fetch all the available Shipping method`**?
- Which **`Layout`** or **`Template`** in Magento core is making the **`fetching`** and **`displaying process`** for the **`Shipping Methods`** on the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectRates` is responsible for fetching the shipping rates.